# How to reproduce Spark hash function using Python?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, hash

Spark uses Murmur3 algorithm to compute the hash value. I tried using [this Python-based mmh3 package](https://github.com/hajimes/mmh3) to produce a hash but it produces a different hash value from Spark.

I've read lots of relavent questions about Spark's Hash algorithm but I still don't know how to get same hash value in pure Python.

- [What hash algorithm is used in pyspark.sql.functions.hash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67041501/what-hash-algorithm-is-used-in-pyspark-sql-functions-hash)
- [Hash function in spark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53634650/hash-function-in-spark)
- [Scala MurmurHash3 library not matching Spark Hash function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63112959/scala-murmurhash3-library-not-matching-spark-hash-function)